# In Memory Zip File Python Error

Tags: python, amazon-s3, zip, stringio

I'm trying to make an in-memory zip file in Python and upload it to Amazon S3. I've read the similar posts on the matter, but no matter what I try, Windows and Linux (RHEL5) cannot open it (it's corrupt). Here's the code I'm running:

```
f_redirects = StringIO()
f_links = StringIO()
f_metadata = StringIO()

# Write to the "files"

zip_file = StringIO()
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'a', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False)
zip.writestr('redirects.csv', f_redirects.getvalue())
zip.writestr('links.csv', f_bad_links.getvalue())
zip.writestr('metadata.csv', f_metadata.getvalue())

f_redirects.close()
f_links.close()
f_metadata.close()

k = Key(BUCKET)
k.key = '%s.zip' % base_name
k.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
k.set_contents_from_string(zip_file.getvalue())
zip.close()
zip_file.close()
```

Comment: First, have you tried just saving the `.zip` file locally and opening it, to see whether the problem has anything to do with S3 or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the contents of the `ZipFile` before you call `close` on it.

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.close) says:

> You must call `close()` … or essential records will not be written.

On top of that, although it sometimes works, it's actually not legal to call `getvalue()` on a closed `StringIO`. Again, from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html#io.StringIO.getvalue):

> Return a `str` containing the entire contents of the buffer at any time before the `StringIO` object’s `close()` method is called.

Finally, if you're using Python 3.x, you probably want to use `BytesIO` rather than `StringIO`. In fact, you might want to use `BytesIO` even in 2.x, as long as you're using 2.6+.

---

Also, your code would be a lot more readable, and harder to get wrong, if you used `with` statements instead of trying to `close` things manually, and didn't try to "declare your variables at the top" C-style:

```
with BytesIO() as zip_file:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'a', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zip:
        zip.writestr('redirects.csv', f_redirects.getvalue())
        zip.writestr('links.csv', f_bad_links.getvalue())
        zip.writestr('metadata.csv', f_metadata.getvalue())
    zip_contents = zip_file.getvalue()

k = Key(BUCKET)
k.key = '%s.zip' % base_name
k.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
k.set_contents_from_string(zip_contents)
```

If you're using Python 2.x, and want to stay with `StringIO`, it isn't directly usable as a context manager, so you'll have to replace the first line with:

```
with contextlib.closing(StringIO()) as zip_file:
```