# How to zip a file from a request in django, and send to amazon S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, zip

I receive a txt file from a form that posts a request to django. I want to compress the txt file and upload it to s3 in the view function.

```
def s3(request):
    in_memory = io.BytesIO() 
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zip.writestr("file.txt", request.FILES["filename"].read())
    os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'
    conn = S3Connection('xxx', 'xxx', host="s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com")
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('name')
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = "test.txt.zip"
    k.set_contents_from_file(io.BytesIO(zip.read(name='file.txt')))
```

The problem is the file that gets saved is 22kb and doesnt have the actual text file (12mb)

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309509/in-memory-zip-file-python-error

Comment: This link had the answer. Just wrote zip.writestr("name", request.FILES.get("file").read()) instead of his file getting function